# How to integrate existing Wordpress blog into Magento

Tags: wordpress, magento, rss

Our company has an existing Wordpress blog which I would like to integrate into our new Magento site.

I need to show the latest 5 posts on my page. It can either be done via an RSS feed or some other method, but I would prefer to not install Wordpress on the same server so as to lag down my site's server.

Any ideas or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feedburner is the way I chose to go - it was simple and easy to integrate:

```
<script src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/johnsoncreeksmokejuice/xZjR?format=sigpro&nItems=5&    dateLocation=above"
 type="text/javascript" ></script>
<noscript><p>Subscribe to RSS headline updates from: <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com    /johnsoncreeksmokejuice/xZjR"></a></noscript>
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you already have a place to put it?  If you already understand how to theme Magento, you can do this in your template code:

```
<?php $feed= new Zend_Feed_Rss('http://www.example.com/feed'); ?>
```

and then `foreach` loop through `$feed` grabbing `->link()` or `->title()` or whatever else you need.

Let me know if you need more help than this.

Comment: Genius answer. I owe you beer.

Comment: That worked a treat for me, once I added () to ->title(). In simpleXML you don't need the () so I was caught out by that. The data seems a lot cleaner with no non-utf-8 artifacts.

Comment: Yep, if I can remember a fortnight back, it worked a treat. What problems you got with it?

Comment: Wondering if it worked for Meghan.  If it did, please accept as answer.

Answer (score 4):

see if this plugin will work
http://fishpig.co.uk/wordpress-integration.html

Answer (score 0):

There are two very good answers on here already. The DiY RSS feed with the Zend library is brilliant (exactly what I wanted myself, rolling my own, right now...). The use-the-Fishpig-integration answer is very sound advice (that module is fantastic).

However Meghan may want something out the box, installable in five minutes rather than lots of time lost fettling. The module by EM themes does the job, looks the part and has options in admin so the feed can be shown neatly regardless of source.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/em-rss-atom-news-feed-widget.html

Comment: Thanks guys!! I did end up going the RSS route - its working nicely! Thanks for all the wonderful suggestions.